# Are there any sila / vinaya for mind?

Tags: five-precepts, vinaya, lay-practices, thoughtprocess

There are five precepts.

1. I don't kill living species.
2. I don't do sexual miaconduct.
3. ........

Similary, Are there any for mind ? Like,

1. I don't think ......
2. ....

We can think according to the five precepts , Not thinking about killing or harming others etc. However, are there any especially for mind ?

Is "indriya samvara" some thing like that ? If it is, how to practise it ?

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of Sankhara. Mano,Vaci and Kaya.
Avoiding Vaci Sankhara and Kaya Sankhara considered Sila. They are also called "Papa"
Suppressing Mano Sankhara considered as Samadhi. These are also termed Kusala when practice in conjunction with Sila.

http://buddhismpathtowellbeing.blogspot.com/2017/11/18-avoid-ten-immoral-actions-dasa.html

There is another set of precepts called eight and ten precepts. They are considered higher Sila as it contained Sila required to contain wholesome mental activities.
To answer your question I would say that Samadhi is the Sila for the mind. Even the term is not used in that way.

Answer (score 1):

There are "Dhamma lists" listed here: [Dhamma Lists](https://www.insightmeditationcenter.org/books-articles/dhamma-lists) -- many of these are lists of (harmful) mental states to avoid or escape, or of (beneficial or virtuous) mental states to cultivate.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, actually there any sil and vinaya. Vinaya Pitakaya is the book you should read to know about it.

There are kind of sil. Basic sil is Pansil.

Atasil and Dasasil which are observe in poya day.

Samanera sil for samanera monk.

Upasampada sil for upasampada monk.